# Archiving options in drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

Apart from unpublishing a node for example, what are the other archiving options for outdated, no longer used pages in the site?

Is there a way to somehow archive the deleted pages?

I am running drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use node archive module or auto archive module, they give a lot of stuffs to do. you can also type archive in search section in drupal.org nd choose modules to display all kind of modules about archiving.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lots of ways doing this.

However, *deleting* the page in Drupal will destroy its content, so if you want to archive *deleted* pages, you will have to implement an archiving solution "outside" of Drupal.  For example a custom Drupal module to bundle up outdated content (including fields, tags, etc.) to a database table or flat file "outside" Drupal, and then delete it and associated fields from the Drupal database.

If writing a custom module to move the outdated content "out of" Drupal is considered too much work, my approach to this (within Drupal) would be to create a taxonomy tag `outdated`. and use it to tag outdated pages after unpublishing them.  Then I would use the **Views** module to create a view listing all pages with this tag.  This would be the administrator's view of the archive of outdated pages.  Since the node is still managed by Drupal, it can be restored to full published status at any time, using standard Drupal administrator commands.

You may also want to add a view (or a context switch) to view all unpublished pages *without* this tag. This to give the administrator an uncluttered view of unpublished pages that is *not* outdated (e.g. those that are yet to be published).

(There is also the [Node Archive](http://drupal.org/project/node_archive) module.  However, it is still in development for Drupal 6 and there is no Drupal 7 port in sight, so this will not work for Drupal 7 unless you're willing to do the Drupal 7 port yourself.)